# Is there an alternative of TrivialProxy for linux?

Tags: linux, iptables

Does anyone knows an alternative software of TrivialProxy for linux? iptables is not enough because I need a GUI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look for a GUI interface to `iptables` ? There are several such things.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, TrivialProxy is a network activity logger.

For this purpose I can recommend using full-featured network sniffer like **Wireshark**.

Not it only can show HTTP,POP3 and other staff supported by TrivialProxy but many more protocols.

It is a GUI program, no fear.

In comparison with TrivialProxy:

- it is more complicated but also much more powerful
- you have not to redirect the traffic, because being sniffer it just intercepts it.